# Black Scholes Separable Solutions

Tags: black-scholes

I want to find all the solutions of the Black Scholes PDE that are of the form $f(x,t)=\theta(x)$ or $f(x,t)=\phi(t)$.

Can someone explain and help with this? I know the PDE formula is

$f_{t}(t, x)=-\frac{1}{2} \sigma^{2}x^2 f_{x x}(t, x)-r x f_{x}(t, x)+rf(t, x)$

$f(T, x)=h(x)$

Thank you!

Comment: I also need to find solutions that are of the form of phi(t)*theta(x) and figure out what terminal value problems I can solve with these solutions? Can you assist? I am so lost.

Comment: If the solution is of the form theta(x) that means it is not a function of t. So the derivative with respect to t namely $f_t(t,x)$ can be set to zero; the equation becomes a ODE. Similarly if the solution is of the form phi(t), you can set all the derivatives with respect to x to zero, resulting in an extremely simple equation, easy to solve.

Comment: So, I will end up with $\theta(x)=-\frac{1}{2} \sigma^{2}(x) f_{x x}(x)-x$ and with r(t)f(t)=phi(t). Is this right?

Comment: And for the part that I asked in the comments, should I just be multiplying these solutions together? I am not sure what terminal vlaue problem I can solve with these.

Comment: No. You end up with $0 = -\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2(x)\theta^{"}(x) -r(x)x\theta^{'}(x)+r(x)\theta(x)$ which you have to solve for Theta. (Are $\sigma$ and $r$ really a function of x ? in the original BS PDE they are constant. The equation you give in your question is more general than BS).

Comment: You are right! They are constants!

Comment: $f_{t}(t, x)=-\frac{1}{2} \sigma^{2} x^{2} f_{x x}(t, x)-r x f_{x}(t, x)+r f(t, x)$ I think this is actually the formula i want to work with

Comment: Do the phi(t) case first, the solution is $\phi(t)=K e^{rt}$

Comment: can you explain why it is that? I get phi(t)=r*phi(t) if I erase all the x derivatives out. Not sure

Comment: Yeah, phi'(t) = r*phi(t). The derivative is equal to r times the function, the solution is phi(t)=K exp(rt). Have you ever taken Differential Equations?

Comment: No, I have not :( This may be part of my problem, hah

Answer (score 1):

$f(t,x)=\theta(x)$ means that the actual price deos not depend on time so:
$$f(t,x)=f(T,x)=h(x)$$ 
so the only solution is $h(x)$.

$f(t,x)=\phi(t)$ means that the price deos not depend on the price.it means that at time T:
$$f(T,x)=\phi(t)=h(x)$$
so if h depend on x, there is no solution and if h is constant, there is one solution $\phi=h$

Comment: Thank you! this is helpful. So when it asks what can be solved if f(T,x)=theta(x)*phi(t) what does this mean? Does this mean we can solve stuff with any of the solutions above?

Answer (score 1):

You may find it useful to look at the method of "separation of variables" for the heat equation (it is often used for a PDE on a bounded domain, but could still be useful).